# Adjusting format of drop-down menu on wordpress site

Tags: html, wordpress, menu, navigation

My site is [manayunkfarm.org] (sorry, can't post more than 1 link), My issue is that if I add more than 4 pages to my menu navigation, the navigation "hamburger" icon slides into white space on all pages with a shorter header image. (Click around the site and use the drop down navigation and you should get an idea of what I'm talking about.

I've mocked up what I'd like for it to look like,

[mockup of possible new navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfk4P.jpg)

I figure it should be fairly easy to adjust the with of each navigation box in half, then create 4 more boxes, doubling the number of pages I can link to, in the same amount of space. Does anyone know where I would have to go in my wordpress editor to edit this and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, opening effect and the stacking of the menu items are being handled by some jquery/javascript somewhere.

What you can do is use [String Locator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/string-locator/) to locate which part of the code is responsible for changing the css of the #nav element. Then, change the code according to your preference. But, if you are not used to scripting then this will be tough.

The way out, which is my suggestion is that, change the color of the menu button.

Change it from white to the pink color being used for the menu link hover : #DBBFBE

If you want to go ahead with thi suggestion then:

Go to Appearance -> Editor. Generally, the editor should open style.css which is the default stylesheet of your theme.

Search for : #nav-toggle

Change the color attribute to #DBBFBE from whatever it is, I think its #ffffff;

Thanks.

Comment: also, if you still want to do the jquery tweaking...then i gotta take a look at your code...only then can we come up with a solution